# Sinon-chai calledWith(new Error()) and with exact message

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I need to test this function :

```js
   //user.js
    function getUser(req, res, next){
    helper.get_user(param1, param2, (err, file) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
    }
```

This is my test function :

```js
it ("failed - helper.get_user throws error", sinon.test(function () {
    var req, res;
    var get_user = this.stub(helper, "get_user")
    get_user.yields(new Error("message"));
    var next = sinon.spy(next);
    user.get_user(req, res, next);
    expect(next).to.have.been.calledWith(new Error("other message"));
}))
```

For my assertion I'm using [sinon-chai](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai/) syntax.

This test is passing even though I would expect it to fail, because my code doesn't throw a message with the error.

How can I test that an error is thrown with correct message?

Comment: Check if my answer is what you are looking for and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

What I usually do is:

```
const next = stub();
someMiddleware(req, res, next);
expect(next).to.have.been.called();
const errArg = next.firstCall.args[0];
expect(errArg).to.be.instanceof(Error);
expect(errArg.message).to.equal("Your message");
```

Note that I am using [dirty-chai](https://github.com/prodatakey/dirty-chai) to be eslint friendly.

HTH,

Answer (score 14):

Since you are using Sinon, you could also take advantage of the [matchers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.0/matchers/). For example:

```
const expectedErr = { message: 'Your message' }

sinon.assert.calledWith(next, sinon.match(expectedErr))
```

This will check against a plain object. A more precise check would be

```
const expectedErr = sinon.match.instanceOf(Error)
  .and(sinon.match.has('message', 'Your message'))

sinon.assert.calledWith(next, sinon.match(expectedErr))
```

Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1373) for more details.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisSharp, this is the better answer

Answer (score 1):

A more complete example to complement @Alex response:

```js
expect(next).to.have.been.calledWith(
  sinon.match.instanceOf(Error)
    .and(sinon.match.has(
      'message',
      'Some message',
    )
  )
);
```