# Testing next middleware is called with particular error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Consider I have this branch of code:

```
if (somethingGood) {
  // do something
} else {
  const error = new Error('Some specific message');
  next(error);
}
```

How can I assert that next is called with that error message (next is stubbed using `sinon.stub()`)?

I initially tried:

```
expect(next.calledWith('Some specific message')).to.eql(true);
```

But, of course that does not work because next was actually called with an error.

Comment: you haven't told us what testing lib you're using

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119260/sinon-calledwithnew-error-and-with-exact-message) helpful? Looks like a duplicate to me, but my vote is binding. )

Comment: Why does it matter which testing lib I'm using? I don't need a syntactically correct answer, I'm just not sure how to assert against an error object.

Comment: We need to know the assertion library so we can tell you how to assert against an object with that library. At the moment you're just asserting against a string in that example, so I'd imagine you could just do `next.calledWith(new Error('Some specific message'))` but couldn't tell you for sure unless I knew the library.